# Script to enable AJAX for asp.net in web config

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I've created a custom WSS 3.0 application which uses [ASP.NET for AJAX](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en)

The problem is that I always have to modify web.config according to [this directions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861898.aspx)

I was just wondering if anyone has created a script to do this so I won't have to edit web.config manually for each server on the farm.

This would really be a best practice to use a script like this since the current scenario will cause problems, e.g. when users extend the current web application. I've seen people do great things with tool like [stsadmwebconfig](http://stsadmwebconfig.codeplex.com/).

If someone hasn't done anything similar then I'll have to create this myself. If I do I'll publish the solution here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Ajaxify MOSS](http://www.codeplex.com/ajaxifymoss) by Rich Finn. Make sure to use the `addajax35` option.

Also on another thread Johan posted a link to this download by [Scot Hilier](http://features.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2502#DownloadId=33434). Presumably it works but I haven't found any documentation on what it actually does.

Comment: @Alex  - it´s a wsp with a feature that adds the required stuff to your web.config file (a webapp scoped feature).

Comment: @Johan: Thanks for the clarification. Does it just add AJAX support or WCF and other stuff as well?